# Is there a way to limit the number of foreign key references for a single table index

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm having difficulty finding an answer because I'm having difficulty expressing the question. So I apologize if their is a duplicate (or similar) question on here.

Is there a way to limit the number of references to a specific foreign key in MySQL?

Explained via Metaphor:

Imagine it as a study group with a 'leader'. You have a 'leaders' table, and you have a 'members' table.

Is there a way to prevent each 'leader' from having more than 'x number' of 'members' *assigned* to them via foreign key?

Or is this something I would have to do when creating the 'members' in the first place? ie. some way to check how many references already exist and change the foreign key if the ID is > 'x number'

Thank you for any help or direction you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a very clean solution, but it might work.

Suppose that you have a `Leader` table and a `Member` table. Create a third table, `LeaderMember`. This should have three columns, `LeaderID`, `MemberID`, and `MemberNumber`. `LeaderID` and `MemberID` are both foreign keys to the respective tables.

`CREATE TYPE` for the `MemberNumber` column, restricting the integer values that it can take, for example from 1 to 8.

Now impose two constraints on the table. First a `UNIQUE` constraint on `MemberID`, which ensures that a member can only have one leader. Then a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of columns `(LeaderID, MemberNumber)`. This will mean that each leader can only have as many members as there are distinct values possible for `MemberNumber`.

I can see a couple of drawbacks with this - first of all inserting a new `Member` is now a little tricky, as you have to find a value of `MemberNumber` which has not been used. Bear in mind you have to make a check at this point anyway - to see if the `Leader` in question already has enough members. Secondly the type for the `MemberNumber` might suggest that there is some difference between the members which have the different values - that the numbers are meaningful.

However, I think it is a reasonably clean and normalized design.

Comment: Yeah, I think a third table is the way to go. Not 100% sure how I'm going to implement it completely, but I think it's the right strategy! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, similar to this answer: [Constrain/limit certain records in sql table definitions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116592/constrain-limit-certain-records-in-sql-table-definitions/116727#116727)